# How to check if the excel workbook is currently working on a MAC or Windows

Tags: windows, macos, excel, vba

I have a workbook with some automations to reconfigure paths and destiny, as it opens in many different file structures.

(example, the same workbook open at '//user/dropbox' and //user/documents/dropbox') etc

For each user, it have a different initial path. (example, one of the automation create a folder structure inside "/dropbox/comercial/project number".

It works fine in windows, but when i try to run it in a mac it gives an error.
apparently, the file path its right, but the "/" is to the other side "\".
   so the result is something like "\user\documents\dropbox/comercial/project number"

Im not sure if this is the problem, but, if it is, how could i solve?

im thinking about make a macro to check if its running on mac or windows, and, for each, "reconfigure" the paths with the right symbol.

Im not sure if i was clear enough. if not, please, ask and i will try to explain!

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two options:

1) Use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of "/" - like in a function:

```
Function BuildPath(sections As Variant) As String
    BuildPath = Join$(sections, Application.PathSeparator)
End Function

'// Example use
'
'   Dim sections As Variant
'   sections = Array("documents", "projects", "files", "myfile.xlsx")
'   
'   Debug.Print BuildPath(sections)
'//
' ~~> output (e.g. Windows): documents\projects\files\myfile.xlsx
```

2) Use conditional compilation to check the environment:

```
#If Mac Then
    Const ps As String = "/"
#Else
    Const ps As String = "\"
#End If

'// rest of code here, using "ps" as path separator
```